# Is there an R function for finding a specific value and pasting it to the next cell to the right(next column same row number)

Tags: excel, vba

I have a report that contains values in two columns (B:C), when column B has a value, column C has an empty cell for the same row.

What I want to achieve is to create a macro to search for a specific value (i.e "Desktop") in the column A and if it matches the search, copy/cut the value and paste it one cell to the next column but in the same row (that is meant to be blank), so all the values are aligned in one column (i.e "Desktop" found in A1, then paste it to B1 without creating a new column).

Example:

[image]

Comment: By *R function* in title, are you referring to the [R programming language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r)?

Comment: Could you just create a new column that is like `IF(B1="", C1, B1)` in column D, copy down, and then just copy/paste-values that fully complete column D whereever you like? VBA seems like overkill here. Also you say "Column A" for `Desktop`, but your screenshot suggests this should be column `B`, thus my example `if()` formula is more aligned to your screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3 ways to get the job done.

```
Dim cel As Range

    'This will search for "Desktop" and copy it to the cell on the right.
    For Each cel In Range("B2", Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        If cel.Value = "Desktop" Then
            cel.Offset(, 1).Value = cel.Value
            'The line below will remove "Desktop" from the cell if required
            'cel.ClearContents
        End If
    Next cel

    'Or

    'This will search for "Desktop", insert a cell and shift to the right.
    For Each cel In Range("B2", Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        If cel.Value = "Desktop" Then
            cel.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
        End If
    Next cel

    'Or

    'This will search for any empty cell in Col C and copy the value from Col B.
    For Each cel In Range("C2", Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp))
        If cel.Value = "" Then cel.Value = cel.Offset(, -1).Value

        'The line below will remove "Desktop" from the cell if required
        'cel.Offset(, -1).ClearContents
    Next cel
```